# Prevent build from putting in base href into index.html

Tags: angular

When doing a build:

```
ng build --prod --aot=false
```

It always puts in a `<base href>` in the index.html in the dist folder. Is there a way I can prevent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To not get `<base href="/">` on the dist `index.html`, remove it from the `src/index.html` file:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>PROJECTNAME</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
...
```

Should be, then:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>PROJECTNAME</title>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
...
```

## The `ng build` `--base-href` flag

It is important to notice that the `ng build` command [has a `--base-href` (or `--bh`) flag](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build#base-tag-handling-in-indexhtml), but it only works for changing the `href` attribute (if it exists) or adding it (if it doesn't exist). [It doesn't allow you to remove it](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/@angular/cli/lib/base-href-webpack/base-href-webpack-plugin.ts#L19-L32).

Comment: Why that would be in there by default... i don't understand. Thanks for this!